# Cron not running

Tags: google-app-engine

My cron has stopped running. If I enter the url manually it works. But the cron page in dashboard says "Hasn't been run". I tried changing frequency, timezone but to no avail.

My cron.yaml looks:

```
cron:

- description: clear data
  url: /data
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

Does any one has any idea on why its not running ? Please help.

Comment: That's odd, have you checked the logs?

Comment: The log has only the ones that I had run manually.

Comment: what is your application id ?

Comment: maybe the url is set to `login: required` in the apps.yaml file?

Comment: In case you found a solution to your problem please let us know as I am facing exactly the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the error was that I didn't return `HTTP 200` in the cron handler.

**Edit:**
It also didn't work (with symptoms as described in the OP) when I just scheduled it as "every 24 hours". When I changed it to "daily 10.00" it worked.

Comment: I tried with "every 1 minutes" and "every 10 minutes", and it did not work for me on this date.  I eventually found another source of timing I could use, but I have no idea what was going on.  I did return HTTP 200.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Using:

```
schedule: every 1 mins
```

works.  Apparently, "mins" works.  I was not able to make it work with "minutes".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this matters, but you could try
    schedule: every 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

Have you set OK http response to the end of your servlet ? Like that :

```
//Set Http Response To 200
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
//Set ContentType
res.setContentType("text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work. Tried mins and minutes. Yes, the job returns a 200, but its not even getting called in the first place.
A search of the logs reveals zero invocations.

My app was in node, I ended up using `setInterval` to work around it.